# Unity Editor not zooming properly

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a problem with the scene editor, as you can see in the images below, every time I zoom into the ground (for example with the right mouse button and WASD) it is as if I passed through it, basically I cannot put myself on the street level and it is really annoying. It happened at a random moment and I have no idea how to fix it, has someone already had this problem or knows how to fix it?
Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting a game object and click f to focus the scene camera on it, this might fix the issue

Answer (score 1):

select game object and press f then it'll be okay

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).